# Ajax delay request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am getting weird behavior,

I am calling ajax continuously after the first call , First is on drop down select, Another is continuous on a delay , First one calls after selecting a city from a drop down, I store that value in a global variable,

```
$('.selectCity').change(function () {
    var city = $(this).val();
    ...
    ...
```

Then i use that `city` in an ajax call like :

```
var timer, delay = 3000;

timer = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/riders/location/track',
    data: {
       'city': city
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

When i select a city, Suppose `london`, **Then** the delay ajax request calls and the result comes expected,

**But when i again select another city lets say `Boston` then the delay method calls two times one for `london` and another for `Boston`, Which should only calls for `Boston`.**

Comment: Can you supply the entire setup?

Comment: "_I have two calls of ajax_" Nope, you're continuously calling ajax in interval of 3 secs.

Comment: @FelixMosheev , Here is the code https://pastebin.com/rpnbVyH0

Comment: @Teemu updated...

Comment: Please re-read my comment. [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is not just a delay method.

Comment: @Teemu Updated again

Comment: @Teemu any solution ? Here is the complete coded https://pastebin.com/rpnbVyH0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are defining an interval for each city change, but not clearing it after the city is changed, so you got an accumulated intervals.

> **setInterval(callback, ms)**
>
> Schedules callback to be called repeatedly every ms milliseconds. Any additional arguments are passed straight through to the callback.

If you want only to delay the Ajax request once, you should use `setTimeout` api instead.

Comment: So i have to use `setTimeout()`, instead of `setInterval()` ?

Comment: If all you want is to delay one request, yes. setInterval was invented for multiple time base actions.

Comment: I have to call to the last city select from the drop down, That's call i want.

Comment: Ok, so `setTimeout` will allow you to delay each ajax request that was fired due to city change.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the `setInterval handler` before you call it again.
More information is here
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

In your case it is

```
var timer, delay = 3000;

// Clear out the previous timer.
// This will start a new timer again.
clearInterval(timer);

timer = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/riders/location/track',
    data: {
       'city': city
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: I think i don't need to clear the timer, I have to make a call with last city selected.

Comment: @Gammer Problem here is every time you select new option from the dropdown it will add a new timer and it is bound to the value it provided. So if you want to call it for the last selected option only, you should clear the previous interval and start another interval with the new city. Or you can use a closure.